# PyCharm ver. Community 2020.2 debugger buttons (Step over, Step into code...) not working?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Everyone,

the title of the question says it all, do you have any ideas how this can be fixed so that I can analyse the code execution step-by-step?

@Pave_Karateev,

please find the below screenshot with breakpoints included and Debugger ON. The buttons are still not clickable. Could you please advise what is the order of the Debugging process in case I am doing something wrong so that I can have this working?

p.s. sorry for my late reply - did not have access to a PC over the last couple of days :)

10nx for checking into this!

[image: m]

[image]

Comment: sometimes pycharm it can be a little bit slow depending on your computer, that happends to me, and I only have to wait on till it works

Comment: I run quick scripts, not major loads and the CPU is i7 Gen 4 with 8GB RAM - I do not think that resources are the problem but rather a kind of bug...?

Comment: For "Step over" and other buttons to be enabled execution should be stopped on the breakpoint. Is it the case?

Comment: I think the program waits for user input in the `Console` tab.